# BeginInvoke not firing inside a Thread in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this simple code in a WPF application:

```
ThreadStart start = delegate()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("HEY!");

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(
            delegate()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inside invoke?!");
            }
        )
    );
};

new Thread(start).Start();
```

`HEY!` gets printed after a moment as it should and the application is *not* blocked as one would expect from the use of threads, however, why do I never see `Inside invoke?!`? I also tried different priorities like `Send`, which I believe is the highest priority.

I've also tried putting breakpoints inside, and it never stopped there.

Comment: You seem to be writing to a console. What console? There's no console in a WPF application. Where did you expect to see the output? Did you put breakpoints inside this action to see that it is successfully executed?

Comment: Visual Studio debugger console.

Comment: Yes, seriously it's not that simple problem :) I've tried producing error code and writing to files and breaking and console logging. Nothing happens. I'm positive the code never runs.

Comment: My guess is that first thread is terminated before the second thread has a chance to run.

Comment: @ChrisGessler too bad that is not the case here -- it's a WPF application and it stays open.

Comment: @rFactor - hmmm. Looks like I was correct, just didn't say it quite right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Few basics first -**

- Each thread had its own Dispatcher and Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher will always returns the Dispatcher for the thread which is currently in execution.
- BeginInvoke execute your specified delegate asynchronously as per the priority specified by DispatcherPriority.

**Issue with the code -**
You are placing the delegate on Dispatcher queue for the secondary thread you have created. But before the secondary thread gets the time to execute it, your secondary thread exited and hence its dispatcher. That's why the delegate never get executed.

There are two ways you can achieve this -

*Either queue the delegate on the dispatcher synchronously like this -*

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Inside invoke?!");
                        }
                    )
                );
```

*Or you can queue it on the dispatcher of your main thread (often called UI thread) like this -*

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Inside invoke?!");
                        }
                    )
                );
```